# XNA and WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, xna, sprite

I was wondering If there was a way to have an xna game within a windows forms or in vice versa. I have found several examples online, but I couldn't understand what they were doing. I was also wondering if there was a way to make a sprite act like a button on a winforms...is it possible to click on a sprite?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, on all.

Sprite act like a button on winforms:
use the [onclick event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.click.aspx)

Xna Game within Windows Forms:
You would need to add a reference to the Xna.framework.something ... sorry kinda out of touch which class implements it but a lot of examples on the xna forums by the community
It should generate a toolbox control to be able to drag and drop.
Example: Nick Gravelyn's Tile Editor... it's youtube based which take you through it step by step.

Winforms into Xna Game:
I would say not to rely on adding a winform objects to xna games as it would not always work. e.g: running on xbox360 :D
Though, it would be same thing as above for the answer.
Examples: [Winforms components into xna](http://roecode.wordpress.com/2008/02/29/xna-framework-gameengine-development-part-15-adding-winform-support-step-1-to-world-builder/)