# How to run a C# winform in an XNA C# project

Tags: c#, xna, pdfsharp

I am trying to use the PDFsharp library in an XNA game.  The example code I am trying to get to work is:

```
 static void Main() 
    {
      Renderer renderer = new Renderer();
      PreviewForm form = new PreviewForm();
      form.RenderEvent = new PagePreview.RenderEvent(renderer.Render);
      Application.Run(form);
    }
```

But I don't know how to get this to run in XNA.

Is it possible to pass the graphics that are passed to the winform to the XNA graphics engine instead?

Comment: possible duplicate of [XNA and WinForms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317562/xna-and-winforms)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### update 2

It appears that the original links to MSDN have been broken, I can't seem to find them on MSDN anymore, if someone does, please update the post. In the mean time you may want to check out this codeproject article -- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21330/Easy-Rendering-with-XNA-Inside-a-Windows-Form

**update** after a quick check, looks like the first link at (See also: [XNA and WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317562/xna-and-winforms)) is the same one I found.

I recommend you look into mixing winforms and XNA, try this: http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/winforms_series_1

Comment: @user1306322 I have updated my post with another link and a request for anyone who finds the new location of the broken link to update the post.

Answer (score 0):

The First thing you need to do is to create the login form.
in this form create the fields you need as public properties

```
public string userName {get;set;} 
public string password {get;set;}
```

in the login form you need to write the user info to those properties:

```
private void btnOk_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    this.userName = txtName.Text;
    this.password = txtPass.Text;
    this.Close();
}
```

then, in the game (in the part you need) write something like this:

```
using (var form = new frmLogin())
{
    var result = form.ShowDialog();
    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string user = form.userName;
        string pass = form.password;
    }
}
```

But as an FYI - winforms don't look so good in XNA
Hope it helps