# How to show WinForm and then run XNA game?

Tags: c#, xna

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Embed XNA in WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558132/embed-xna-in-winforms)

HEY, please this is NOT DUPLICATE of that post. Its because you cant get any answer from 
  it because its links are not working...  and someone comments me that 
  he got new link and when i saw that site it wasnt that i need...

I am making game that needs to login, and i want to make login in WinForm... but when i run winform and then after successfull login it should run game. I saw this [Post on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7166440/how-to-run-a-c-sharp-winform-in-an-xna-c-sharp-project) but the link for answer is ... abanonded ...

Comment: I'd make the xna app a separate exe file and use the process library to start it from the other application, passing some type of authentication key if you need on the command line.

Comment: See this question [Embed XNA in WinForms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558132/embed-xna-in-winforms)

Comment: @TJHeuvel i dont want winform IN xna game i want it as ... messagebox...

Comment: @asawyer But when someone rename that game ??

Comment: @GemHunter1 So they can't play.

Comment: @GemHunter1 Are you sure? Romoku has a very good answer.

Comment: @GemHunter1 do you want make something like loader?

Comment: @asawyer :) it didnt reloads me, i see it now :)

Comment: Microsoft changed it to xbox.create.msdn, heres the correct link about XNA and winforms. http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/winforms_series_1

Comment: You won't get a reopen vote if you scream like this..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

XNA is bootstrapped in the `Program.cs`. Just add code in your winforms when the client is authenticated that starts the XNA game like in the `Program.cs`.

See http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/303672/XNA-And-Windows-forms

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        button1.Text = "Start!";
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread theThread = new Thread(StartGame);
        theThread.Start();
    }
    public void StartGame()
    {
        Game1 game = new Game1();
        game.Run();
    }
}
```